# Inspect response when i use a view Class-based views - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to inspect the response for know the params of pagination. I try used Pdb but the application stops. I think to overwrite some method like `def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` but i don't know if the best way, someone could guide me ?

```
class PostsFeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    template_name = 'posts.html'
    model = Post
    ordering = ('-created',)
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    #   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `get`:

```
class PostsFeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    ...

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return response
```